# DropDuplicates is not giving expected result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on a use-case of removing duplicate records from incoming structured data (in the form of CSV files within a folder on HDFS). In order to try this use-case, I wrote some sample code using files option to see if duplicates can be removed from the records that are present in the CSVs that are copied to the folder (HDFS).

Find below the codepiece:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}


val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").getOrCreate()
val userSchema = new StructType()
    .add("prod_code", "string")
    .add("bal", "integer")
    .add("v_txn_id", "string")
    .add("timestamp", "Timestamp")

val csvDF = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",")
                            .schema(userSchema)
                            .csv("/user/Temp")
csvDF.dropDuplicates("v_txn_id")
csvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

val dbDf2 = spark.sql("select prod_code, bal, v_txn_id, current_timestamp timestamp from table1")
dbDf2.writeStream.queryName("aggregates").outputMode("update").format("memory").start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show();
```

Now, when I copy a file in the folder with duplicate records (by v_txn_id), i still see that the result sink gets all the rows from the file:

```
P1,1000,TXNID1
P1,2000,TXNID2
P1,3000,TXNID2
P1,4000,TXNID3
P1,5000,TXNID3
P1,6000,TXNID4
```

All these rows in the csv file get moved to the result "aggregates". What I am expecting is:

```
P1,1000,TXNID1
P1,3000,TXNID2
P1,5000,TXNID3
P1,6000,TXNID4
```

This is the first time I am attempting structured streaming (with state), so pardon me for trivial question. Any suggestions would help a lot.

Comment: Just based on the description it sounds like you're looking for complete mode, not update mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per you expected output, I believe that you need to find the max of bal based on `prod_code` and `v_txn_id` column. To achieve you output, on your final `aggregate` table, you can use a window funtion (`partition by`) to find the max of `bal` based on `prod_code` and `v_txn_id` column by created a temporary column called `temp_bal`. Then in the outer query select distinct values based on `prod_code`, `temp_bal` and `v_txn_id` columns.

```
spark.sql("select distinct prod_code,temp_bal as bal,v_txn_id from(select *,max(bal) over(partition by prod_code,v_txn_id) as temp_bal from aggregates) order by prod_code,v_txn_id").show()
```

[image]
**EDIT 1 :**

As per your requirment please find the below script that will work according to the latest date/time for the `v_txn_id`.

```
spark.sql("select distinct a.prod_code,a.bal,a.v_txn_id from aggregates a join (select distinct v_txn_id,max(timestamp) over(partition by v_txn_id) as temp_timestamp from aggregates) b on a.v_txn_id=b.v_txn_id and a.timestamp=b.temp_timestamp order by a.v_txn_id").show()
```

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions, else please mark this answer as accepted (tick icon).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. But actually, the balance may not be maximum. I have put an incremental balance for this sample run. Balance can be less for the same v_txn_id (erroneous previous transaction). So, in totality I am interested in the final value of the v_txn_id that has come as a part of the injestion process. So, in above example: P1,2000,TXNID2 / P1,4000,TXNID3 are actually erroneous transactions.

Comment: Do you want to take the latest "v_txn_id" based on "timestamp" column? @BDA

Comment: Yes, that will also do in case dropduplicates doesn't remove the old v_txn_ids. My assumption was that Dropduplicates will only give me the latest v_txn_ids. Anyways, if we can achieve it through timestamp column then it should work for me. Based on this small code piece it appears that my understanding of DropDuplicates is wrong (presumptuous).

Comment: How can I apply Window (with/without watermark) and use processing time to get the latest v_txn_ids. The use-case then would be: multiple transactions have come in during the sliding window of let's say 5 minutes, and I want to get the latest transaction ids for that window of 5 minutes. Also, the next window transactions will be totally different from the previous window.

Comment: I have added the answer. Please go through and let me know if you have any questions @BDA